# Attachment size on exchange OWA with squid

Tags: exchange, squid, outlook-web-app

We have a size limit of attachment on exchange 2016 for 25MB.
It works with outlook client but not with owa clients.
We can’t attach document larger than 100KB.

When I try to attach, I got a TCP_MISS/413.

```
1531128394.524     16 x.x.x.x TCP_MISS/413 299 POST https://xxxx/owa/service.svc? - FIRSTUP_PARENT/x.x.x.x -
```

Squid Cache: Version 3.5.20

squid.conf

```
    # ----- Global Settings -----

redirect_rewrites_host_header off
cache_mem 256 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 128 KB
#cache_log /dev/null
#cache_store_log /dev/null
#client_persistent_connections on

https_port 443 accel cert=/etc/squid/certificats/xxx.crt key=/etc/squid/certificats/xxx.key defaultsite=xxxx vhost

# ----- Exchange Server -----
#cache_peer xxxx parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER login=PASS name=exchangeServer
#cache_peer xxxx parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER login=PASS connection-auth=off name=exchangeServer
#cache_peer xxxx parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER login=PASS connection-auth=off name=autodiscoverServer
cache_peer xxxx parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER login=PASS name=exchangeServer
cache_peer xxxx parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER login=PASS name=autodiscoverServer

acl webm_url url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/.*$

acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/admin.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/AutoDiscover.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/ecp.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/ews.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/Exchange.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/Exchweb.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/mapi.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/owa.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/oab.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/Public.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/Rpc.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/RpcWithCert.*$
acl webm_pas url_regex -i ^https://xxxx/RpcWithCert/rpcproxy.dll.*$

cache_peer_access exchangeServer allow webm_pas
cache_peer_access exchangeServer deny all

acl webm_red urlpath_regex ^/$
deny_info https://xxxx/owa/ webm_red
http_access deny webm_url webm_red

http_access allow webm_url
never_direct allow webm_url
miss_access allow webm_url

# ----- General -----

miss_access deny all
http_access deny all

# ----- Errors -----

cache_mgr xxxx
error_directory   /usr/share/squid/errors/fr
error_default_language fr
err_page_stylesheet     /etc/squid/errorpage.css
email_err_data on
httpd_suppress_version_string on
visible_hostname xxxxx
```

Can you help me?
Thanks. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not squid but IIS.
Squid change headers so it makes issue[image]

Here's change in Default Web Site/owa Web.config  Section :system.webServer/serverRunTime

Now we can upload 9MB of attachement.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured the client-specific message size limits for OWA via the web.config files on Client Access servers and Mailbox servers?

If not, check this out:

Configure client-specific message size limits
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529949%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**Note:** Base64 encoding increases the size of the message by approximately 33%, so the values you specify for any message size limits should be approximately 33% larger than the actual usable message sizes.

Comment: I m in default values. I've already checked these parameters.